# Protégé export explanation

Tags: owl, protege

Is it possible to export from Protégé the explanations?
I need to extract the "path" that was made for creating the inference.[image]

I see that standard "Export inferred axioms" is not saving the explanations.

Comment: there is no such feature yet: https://github.com/protegeproject/explanation-workbench/issues/22

Comment: Indeed, you could simply write a few lines of Java code to compute and save the explanations as OWL axioms in any form you want

Comment: SO is for programming questions